# MVC3 best way to log request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, logging, request

I want to keep a log of all the requests to my MVC 3 app, including requested URL, user's ip adress, user agent, etc. Where is the best place to do this,

1) use a base controller?

2) use an action filter?

3) others?

Comment: Doesn't IIS do this for you already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do this inside my BaseController. Something like this:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    // If in Debug mode...
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        var message = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    "Leaving {0}.{1} => {2}",
                                    filterContext.Controller.GetType().Name,
                                    filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.Trim(),
                                    filterContext.Result);
        Logger.Debug(message);
    }

    // Logs error no matter what
    if (filterContext.Exception != null)
    {
        var message = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    "Exception occured {0}.{1} => {2}",
                                    filterContext.Controller.GetType().Name,
                                    filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.Trim(),
                                    filterContext.Exception.Message);
         Logger.Error(message);
     }

     base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Hope you get the idea.

You can also log before the action is executed using:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

Answer (score 6):

[An `HttpModule`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95165/Building-a-Simple-Logging-HTTP-Module-with-Logging) seems like the best fit, if you ask me.

All of the data you're talking about logging is available well before any particular Controller gets invoked. So if you do logging outside of the controller, then you get to capture even those requests which are not to valid controller actions. And there's no need to clutter your controller code with something that's really a cross-cutting concern.

Comment: i like your idea and i agree with what you've said, but this time i'm going to go w/ a base controller like Leniel suggested since it's easier to incorporate. later if i get more time, i can switch to httpModule.

Comment: How about using ASP.NET Application events, e.g. Application_BeginRequest/_EndRequest or Application_BeginAuthenticateRequest/_EndAuthenticateRequest. Are there drawbacks for putting logging code in there?

Comment: @RonaldZarīts: Separation of concerns. Logging is not the purpose of Global.asax.cs, so logging code does not belong there. If you set things up in a way that responds to those same events while keeping your logging code in its own class, I'd be fine with that. But that's basically what HttpModules are for.

Answer (score -1):

You can have multiple action methods triggered when rendering a single request. Consider using [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) on your layout page as follows:

```
Html.RenderAction("Navigation", "Menu")
```

It's worth noting that you'd then have two log entries with the same information if you choose to use action filter for logging.